# docker compose for multiple commands

Tags: python, docker

I am unable to run multiple commands for scripts (py) in rulsmalldata service. Can you please provide me solutions.

```
version: "3"

networks:
  mlflow:
    external: true

services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    command:
      - --loglevel warning
    container_name: "redis"

  rulsmalldata:
    image: rulsmalldata:mlflow-project-latest
    command: bash -c "python mlflow_model_run.py && python mlflow_model_serve.py && python mlflow_model_output.py"
    networks:
      - mlflow
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI: <<TRACKING_URI>>
      REDIS_ADDRESS: redis
      AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<<Name>>;AccountKey=<<KEY>>EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your `docker-compose` file so we can help you identify the issue.

Comment: create a bash script ?

Comment: I am using app service of azure to execute the scripts in docker container.

Comment: This should work... What output are you getting

Comment: INFO  - Container logs from rulsmalldata_rulsmalldata_0_7d657479 =  mlflow_model_run.py: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
mlflow_model_run.py: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
mlflow_model_run.py: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
mlflow_model_run.py: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
mlflow_model_run.py: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
mlflow_model_run.py: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file